# Bootstrap Nav fixed-top & layout issues

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a mockup but keep running into issues with the navbar and main content layout. The page needs to look like the mockup image below on desktop.

I've tried everything I can think of and read up on the bootstrap site but continue running into problems.

First the navbar should be fixed so it scrolls with you. I've copied from one of their templates but it doesn't scroll like the demo unless I change it to pull-right. But if I use pull-right it removes the top spacing and first container spacing needed. I've tried the body tag padding-top but all it does is create more space between the nav and main container not above the nav.

The other issue is the row and column layout in desktop. The col-md-8 doesn't line up with the other col-md-4. It looks ok in mobile with 320 wide.

I'm pulling my hair and not sure what needs to fixed. If anyone can spare some time and have a look I'd really appreciate it.

Live links to the files are below.

[link to image mockup](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/mockup.jpg)
[link to live webpage mockup](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/index.html)
[link to css override](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/starter-template.css)

[image: picture of image mockup]

Comment: Sorry, site was down temporarily. Up and running again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be fixed now. Perhaps the biggest issue I was having was getting the navbar in proper locations both desktop & mobile. Originally I was using an override for .nav to modify the margin in order to get the placement right in desktop, but in mobile view it would be in a different position, not to mention it kept sharing the margin ratios of 80px top and 120px right. This would force the toggled menu to be 80px further down rather default 0px. I couldn't figure a way around this so I figured why not try adding a div tag just for the margin spacing. Apparently this seemed to work after adding new info into the media queries. Also fixed a spacing issue when in tablet widths with nav and hero image.

As for the rest of the layout, I used col-md-3 and col-md-7 which pretty much lined everything up right away except for some padding needed. Everything else like h1 and h3 I used a simple class for mobile to adjust the margins again.

If there's an easier way or more efficient way of coding this I'm open to suggestions if anyone has some. [Updated Live Link](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. On your CSS override you have the attribute .navbar (position:relative;)  This overrides your navbar fixed top property.
2. As far as your col-md-4 goes..you have it wrapped in an html descriptor..which is this:  `<!-- -->`.  This just gives descriptions of what html attribute is listed.  These descriptors are on a lot of your actual html and need to be removed in order for the code to work properly.  Remember though some of them are actually descriptors...like `<!--fixed navbar-->`

Answer (score 0):

hii just checked your live website all problems is the way you are using div tags .. so for first section of image and nav bar it should be in one div tag

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">IMAGE</div>
<div class="col-md-8">your nav bar </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
Banner
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
HR MARUTIS STUFF
</DIV>
<div class="col-md-8">
HI LOUREM THINGY 
</div>
</div>
```

and soo on 
HOPE THIS HELP IN YOUR FORMATTING OF PAGE

Comment: OK I think I've fixed the layout for desktop (live page updated). I looks pretty good in mobile as well so far. Except I'd like to remove some spacing and margins, and maybe change layout in a couple breakpoints or media queries. I'm guessing that's the only way to do it. But not exactly sure how to remove spacing in m-queries like the mobile nav when toggled the menu list items are not near top of toggle button and logo. It seems to share margin of desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do I change the margins in the nav? At desktop breakpoint 991 the navigation drops below the logo but maintains the margins leaving a large space between logo and nav. I've tried new classes and etc. but nothing works. Is there a way to break out of it to be adjusted?

The same margins are applied to the mobile toggled menu as well.

Comment: OK I think I've fixed the spacing issue at breakpoint 991 by using a new div with margins and padding. But I still can't figure out for the life of me why the margins are still imported into the mobile nav. Is there ANY way to reset the nav when in mobile to 0s'? The new div is still using margin top 80px and margin right 120px. Mobile nav needs to be reset somehow. Anyone know how to fix this? Please any help is appreciated. thanks